# How to add data to database table in cshtml and asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add data to table in database when click the button.How can I do that?Where should I write code in cshtml or cs?

.cshtml code
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>

        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>
            <ul>

                <li>@Model.Code</li>

            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <br />
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should write code of your data save logic in `Controller`. Please check [Accessing Your Model's Data from a Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller), it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an input via a textbox. You still have to make your controllers and models tho.

ex

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Applicant"))
```

```
        <label>First name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
}
```

If you want to pull data from the database and put it in your table  you have to make your model into a list in your controller

ex

make an instance of your database in your controller

```
 public ApplicantController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
```

turn into context into a list

```
var  CarInsurances = _context.CarInsurancs.ToList();
```

in your controllers return pass the list into the view

```
return View(CarInsurances);
```

In your view you have to pass the model as an IEnumurable

```
@model IEnumerable<Autoloan.Models.Applicant>
```

then finally using a for each loop in your view

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>

        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
            <ul>

                <li>@Model.Code</li>

            </ul>
}
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <br />
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

hope this helps your question is very confusing.